# Use of「ことがわかる」in this sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence

I encountered this sentence in an article from *NHK News web easy*:

今まで国からお金をもらうためには、旅行した人が本当に利用したことがわかる書類などを「Go Toトラベル」の事務所に出さなければなりませんでした。

I cannot understand what 「**本当に利用したことがわかる書類**」means in this case.
Ignoring that part the remaining part of the sentence can be translated as: "Up until now in order to get money from the government, people who have travelled, have to send [**missing part here**] to the 「Go Toトラベル」office".

Now, I know that 利用する means "To use", and by inferring things, maybe, that part can be roughly translated as "**the documents that do really certify that they were on a trip**", but I'm not sure and I cannot see how「**本当に利用したことがわかる書類**」carries that meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be thinking of this meaning of わかる, which is the first meaning you'll find in a monolingual dictionary.

> 物事の意味・価値などが理解できる
> To be able to understand the meaning, value, etc. of something

But the second definition is the one being used here.

> はっきりしなかった物事が明らかになる
> Something that was unclear becomes clear

So, 本当に利用したことがわかる書類 is "a document which makes it clear that [the traveler] really used [whatever it is they used]"

If you check the "regular" NHK News version of the article, it appears this phrase was NHK News Easy's way of explaining the word 宿泊証明書.